# Rename column of dataframes inside a list with its dataframe name

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have multiple dataframes/tibbles with the same exact structure, but different contents. Their name is the only way I can differentiate them. The objective is to merge them all together into one dataframe, with a factor column. The original dataframes have one column for each hour/measurement, so first I want to gather everything.

Imagine columns 5 to 11 of the mtcars df are my hour columns.

```
mt1 <- mtcars
mt2 <- mtcars
mt3 <- mtcars
mt4 <- mtcars

mtlist <- list(m1 = mt1,
               m2 = mt2,
               m3 = mt3,
               m4 = mt4)

require(tidyverse)

mtlist_tidy <- lapply(mtlist, function(x){
  df <- x %>%
    gather(exp, temp_name, 5:11)

  return(df)
})
```

Now I'm stuck. I need to rename the "temp_name" column in each of the dfs inside mtlist_tidy with the name of that df i.e. m1, m2, etc:

```
> head(mtlist_tidy$m1)
   mpg cyl disp  hp  exp temp_name
1 21.0   6  160 110 drat      3.90
2 21.0   6  160 110 drat      3.90
3 22.8   4  108  93 drat      3.85
4 21.4   6  258 110 drat      3.08
5 18.7   8  360 175 drat      3.15
6 18.1   6  225 105 drat      2.76
```

should become

```
> head(mtlist_tidy$m1)
   mpg cyl disp  hp  exp      m1
1 21.0   6  160 110 drat      3.90
2 21.0   6  160 110 drat      3.90
3 22.8   4  108  93 drat      3.85
4 21.4   6  258 110 drat      3.08
5 18.7   8  360 175 drat      3.15
6 18.1   6  225 105 drat      2.76
```

Then `purrr::reduce(mtlist_tidy, full_join)` would work, completing my task.

I guess there must a solution using only `purrr` and skipping lapply, but I'm not that familiar yet with this package.

Comment: Are you aware that the function `bind_rows` has an option to create an "id" column using the names of the list items? Your question sounds as if that might be useful.

Comment: Yes! This is what I needed! I did not know this, thanks. If you submit it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Please feel free to answer it yourself if you like. There's probably also a duplicate somewhere

Comment: just to clarify `purrr::reduce(mtlist_tidy, full_join)` is a join which is different to what `bind_rows`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of ideas:

First, to approach the problem as you are current you could use `map2` to loop through both the list and the names of the list simultaneously.  You can then name the new columns as you go with the list names via `gather_`(for standard evaluation).

```
map2(mtlist, names(mtlist), ~gather_(.x, "exp", .y, names(.x)[5:11]) )
```

Note the next version of **purrr** will have `imap` as a short-cut for looping through a list and the names of the list.  Also, the next version of **tidyr** will use `tidyeval` and `gather_` will be deprecated.

Second, you could keep things in a long format by using `map_df` for the looping instead of `lapply`.  `map_df` uses `bind_rows` at the end under the hood, and you can include a grouping variable for each list via the `.id` argument.

```
mtlist %>%
    map_df(~.x %>% gather("exp", "temp_name", 5:11), .id = "name" )
```

To put your dataset in a wide format from here you can use `spread`.  It takes a little more work in this example because some of the identifying variables like `hp` and `disp` have the same value across multiple rows.

```
mtlist %>%
    map_df(~.x %>% gather("exp", "temp_name", 5:11), .id = "name" ) %>%
    group_by(name) %>%
    mutate( rows = 1:n() ) %>%
    spread(name, temp_name)
```

Answer (score 3):

You may want to add some NSE magic:

```
library(rlang)
mtlist_tidy %>% map2(., names(.), ~rename(.x, UQ(sym(.y)) := temp_name))
```

Comment: I'm glad I came across this; thanks! It's been a while since you answered this, and looking at what `UQ` and `sym` do, you can probably replace both with `!!`? Not sure if that was in place when you answered the question. Additionally, you can do away with your first `.,`. Resulting in: `mtlist_tidy %>% map2(names(.), ~rename(.x, !!.y := temp_name))`

Answer (score 0):

Does this do it?

```
lapply(mtlist_tidy, function(i) {
  names(i)["temp_name"] <- names(mtlist)[i] } )
```

Answer (score 0):

I write a function to rename at specific columns

```
rename_fn <- function(df, col_ind, new_names) {
        names(df)[col_ind] <- new_names
        return(df)
}
```

Then simply use map2 from purrr

```
mtlist_tidy<-mtlist_tidy %>% map2(.,names(mtlist_tidy),
                            ~rename_fn(.x,col_ind = 6,new_names = .y))
```

Comment: you can also modify the custom rename_fn like below to directly pass the variable name you want to change   ```rename_fn <- function(df, col_ind=NULL, new_names,colname=NULL) {
        if(!is.null(colname)&!is.null(col_ind)){
                print(paste("Either",col_ind,"or",colname,"only",sep=""))
                stop()}
        else if (!is.null(colname)){
                col_ind<-which(names(df)==colname)   
        }
                
        
        names(df)[col_ind] <- new_names
        return(df)
} ```